# MongoDB find number

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am adding MongoDB into my discord bot, I have it set so when something happens it does

```
                await ticketSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
                    {
                        $inc: {
                            ticketNumber: 1
                        }
                    }
                )
```

That all works fine, its when I try to find it later that it doesn't work. I am trying to find the ticketNumber no matter what the number is so if its 16 it will show 16 if its 50 it will show 50 and so on. It would be great if I can store whatever the ticketNumber is when I find it into a variable.

This is what I currently have to try and find it not sure what to do lol im new to mongo and js

```
    let result = ticketSchema.find({
        ticketNumber: [42]
    })
```

Comment: So you're not getting the values ?

Comment: I want to just get the value of ticketNumber but if I did like ticketNumber: '1' it would only find it when ticketNumber is 1? I want it to find it no matter what and show me the number

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't think I'm following you. You want to retrieve all the values ?!

Comment: So what my code does is whenever a channel gets opened it increments the ticketNumber by 1, I want to get that number and name the channel to have the current number channel that it is. So if 5 channels got opened the 5th one would be channel #5 and the 6th would be channel#6

Comment: ahhh alright, there are multiple ways to implement this, i'll edit my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
let result = await ticketSchema.find({ ticketNumber: { $in: [ 42 ] } })
```

the above is to find all documents where ticketNumber includes the number 42,  assuming ticketNumber is an array field which might be why your code is failing (this is how you use the find when trying to find against an array field).

instead try this (I noticed you missed out the await, hope this helps :)):

```
let result = await ticketSchema.find({
  ticketNumber: 42
})
```

Comment: sorry I just had that 42 there as a placeholder, I am trying to find ticketNumber no matter what number it is so I can use it somewhere else. for example even if its 5 or 10 it will still tell me what it is

Comment: Oh then you might to filter your result back like `let result = await ticketSchema.find({}).select('ticketNumber')` so it returns the field you need

Comment: okay that worked, another quick question is there an easy way to filter out objectid field
{ _id: new ObjectId("6242166887accf5291d47584"), ticketNumber: 30 } so its just the ticketNumber and would just output "30" for example

Comment: try this `let result = await ticketSchema.find({}).select('ticketNumber -_id')`

Comment: yeah kinda worked now it shows ticketNumber: 31 I just want the number. Might have to sort it out another way but was just wondering if was a simple way to do it after find

Comment: this should do it `let { ticketNumber } = await ticketSchema.find({}).select('ticketNumber -_id')`

Comment: It worked, you are amazing. I am sorry I was so clueless and annoying I am new to js and mongo so had lots of questions <3

Comment: Welcome :) It's alright, I faced the same challenges when starting out with the mongo library for js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243420/discussion-between-sae-and-xanik).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get the last value of the increment:

**-Get the total number of documents:** (*not really recommended*)

By getting the total number of documents(with appropriate filtering *opened/closed*) you would have the value of the last increment since you are incrementing every time you add a document.

```
db.collection.count()
```

**-Get the latest inserted document:** (*recommended*)

The last document inserted will hold the value of your needed increment.

There are a couple of ways to implement this:

```
db.collection.find().skip(db.collection.count())
```

or

```
db.collection.find().sort({ticketNumber:-1}).limit(1)
```

**Note:** in order to select specific field you can specify them in the find function.

**example:**

```
db.collection.find({}, { ticketNumber: 1, _id: 0}).sort({ticketNumber:-1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: Would that not only find the number when its 42?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i can understand you well, but what do you mean by

```
await ticketSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        $inc: { ticketNumber: 1 },
      }
    );
```

this code is trying to increments the ticketNumber field by one, but you haven't give it any filters.

```
findOneAndUpdate(filters, update, options )
```

in order to get a document then use the find():

```
let value= your Value here;
let result = ticketSchema.find({ticketNumber: value})
```